# Struts2 checkboxes returning values in Action class

Tags: jsp, struts2

Im pretty new to struts2, so Im trying to post everything you need to understand my problem,Your help is much appreciated. try to be more clear, i'm in lack of ideas in this problem, even it sounds like a classic .

```
<s:checkbox name="selectedIndex" theme="simple" >
</s:checkbox>
```

I have dynamic number of checkboxes in my JSP.Lets say i have three checkbox in my jsp.Then if user select first and second checkbox then i want a array in action class whose element is {1,2}.If user select first and third checkbox then i want a array in action class whose element is {1,3}.How can i do it in struts2?

i have getter and setter in action class as:

```
public String[] getSelectedIndex() {
return selectedIndex;
}

public void setSelectedIndex(String[] selectedIndex) {
this.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
}
```

so actionClass give me true and false.

In the followin code List1(Stored in session object) is list of StatusDTOs and getter,setter are following
element of StatusDTO is
:-

```
public boolean getIsDisabled()
{
return this.isDisabled;
}

public void setIsDisabled(boolean isDisabled)
{
this.isDisabled=isDisabled;
}

public int getSerialNo()
{
return this.serialNo;
}

public void setSerialNo(int serialNo)
{
this.serialNo=serialNo;
}
```

Actual code in jsp is

```
<%
ArrayList temp=(ArrayList)ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get("List1");
Iterator itr=temp.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
{
StatusDTO psd=(StatusDTO)itr.next();
System.out.println("********"+psd.getSerialNo());
%>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#E6FAFB">
<%=psd.getSerialNo()%>
</td>
<td bgcolor="#E6FAFB">
<%
if(psd.getIsDisabled())
{
%>
<s:checkbox name="selectedIndex" theme="simple" disabled="true">
</s:checkbox>
<%
}
else
{
%>
<s:checkbox name="selectedIndex" theme="simple" value="1">
</s:checkbox>
<%}
%>

</td>
</tr>
<% }
%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Staff** Bean should have

```
private boolean delete; /// with its setter and getter
```

**JSP**

```
<s:iterator name="staffList" status="bean_rowNum">
    <s:checkbox name="staffList[%{#request.attr.bean_rowNum-1}].delete" />
</s:iterator>
```

On submit you will get selected check box as a true

Answer (score 0):

I prefer List to arrays... Get this very short example working and it will show you how to dynamically select check boxes.

The demo lists a number of check boxes labeled by numbers, a box selected from the first list will appear in a second list, boxes selected in the second list will become part of a unordered list.

JSP "checkboxes.jsp"

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>All Check Boxes</h1>
        <s:form action="checkboxes">
            <s:checkboxlist name="selectedBoxes" list="allBoxes"/>
            <s:submit/>
        <h1>Selected Check Boxes</h1>
            <s:checkboxlist name="selectedSelectedBoxes" list="selectedBoxes"/>
            <s:submit/>
        </s:form>
        <h1>Values chosen from selected Check boxes</h1>
        <ul>
            <s:iterator value="selectedSelectedBoxes">
                <li><s:property/></li>
            </s:iterator>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Action Class "Checkboxes.java"

```
package struts2;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Checkboxes extends ActionSupport{
    public List<Integer> allBoxes = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,22,33,44); //ten elements
    public List<Integer> selectedBoxes = new ArrayList();
    public List<Integer> selectedSelectedBoxes = new ArrayList();
}
```

If using conventions this is straight forward if using xml action "checkboxes" maps to class "struts2.Checkboxes"

You can see from the example that there can be a disagreement between the displayed state of the selected checkboxes and what is in the unordered list.  This would be really easy to correct within the action method but would make the example longer and detract from illustrating the functionality of the check boxes.  Further some feel that encapsulating the fields with getters and setters is a good idea but again it would greatly expand the code length.